# Как сделать такое меню как на картинке?

Tags: css3, html5

```
.header
    background-color: #4f4f4f

.logo
    background-image: url('../img/logo.png')

.row
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-around
.menu
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
.logo__img

.menu-list
    list-style-type: none
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
.menu-list2
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    list-style-type: none

.menu__kompani
    color: #fff
    margin-left: 24px
    &:first-child
        margin-left: 0
.menu__item
    margin-left: 3px
    color: #fff
    &:first-child
        margin-left: 0

.menu__item2
    margin-left: 24px
    &:first-child
        margin-left: 0
.poisk
    background-color: red
    width: 23px
    height: 23px
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
.menu__item2_tel
    color: #fff

.menu-list3
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-evenly
    background-color: #519
    list-style-type: none

    padding-top: 10px
    padding-bottom: 10px
    border-top: 1px solid #808284
.menu__item3
    border-left: 1px solid #4e5358
    padding-left: 17px
    color: #fff
.menu__item3_img
    margin-right: 17px
```

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class='logo__img'>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="menu__kompani">
                    О компании 
                </span>
                <span class="menu__kompani">
                    Контакты
                </span>
                <ul class="menu-list">
                    <li class="menu__item">
                        <img src="img/icons/in.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item">
                        <img src="img/icons/youtube.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item">
                        <img src="img/icons/tw.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item">
                        <img src="img/icons/inst.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item">
                        <img src="img/icons/CCl_logo_цветн.png" alt="">
                        CCL
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item">
                        <img src="img/icons/angl.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="menu-list2">
                    <li class="menu__item2 poisk">
                        <img src="img/icons/poisk.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item2">
                        <img src="img/icons/Инстаграм_копия.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu__item2">
                        <span class="menu__item2_tel">
                            +7 499 110 58 32
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="#">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<ul class="menu-list3">
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/RF.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        EAS системы 
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/Датчики.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        Датчики 
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/Этикетки.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        Этикетки 
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/аксессуары.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        аксессуары
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/Исходная_маркировка_st.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        Исходная Маркировка ST
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/RFID.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        RFID 
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item3">
        <img src="img/Слой_3_копия.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
        ALS Этикетки
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в чем именно возникает проблема ?  В [Вашем примере](http://cp62290.tmweb.ru/pos/) меню есть. Вам нужно только немного изменить его и поставить лого по центру, а также сделать серый фон меню.

Comment: @Alex не получается сделать как на макете :(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.header
    background-color: #4f4f4f
.logo
    display: flex
    align-items: center
.row
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-around
.menu
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: flex-end
.menu span
    display: flex
    align-items: center;
.menu-list
    list-style-type: none
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
.menu-list2
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    list-style-type: none

.menu__kompani
    color: #fff
    margin-left: 24px
    &:first-child
        margin-left: 0
.menu__item
    margin-left: 3px
    color: #fff
    &:first-child
        margin-left: 0

.menu__item2
    margin-left: 24px
    &:first-child
        margin-left: 0
.poisk
    background-color: red
    width: 23px
    height: 23px
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
.menu__item2_tel
    color: #fff

.menu-list3
    display: -webkit-flex
    display: -moz-flex
    display: -ms-flex
    display: -o-flex
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-evenly
    list-style-type: none
    padding-top: 10px
    padding-bottom: 10px
.menu__item3
    border-left: 1px solid #4e5358
    padding-left: 17px
    color: #fff
    line-height: 33px
.menu__item3_img
    margin-right: 17px
    vertical-align: middle
```

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class='logo__img'>
            </div>
            <div class="row-menus">
                <div class="row-menu1">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <span class="menu__kompani">О компании</span>
                        <span class="menu__kompani">Контакты</span>
                        <ul class="menu-list">
                            <li class="menu__item">
                                <img src="img/icons/in.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item">
                                <img src="img/icons/youtube.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item">
                                <img src="img/icons/tw.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item">
                                <img src="img/icons/inst.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item">
                                <img src="img/icons/CCl_logo_цветн.png" alt=""> CCL
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item">
                                <img src="img/icons/angl.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="menu-list2">
                            <li class="menu__item2 poisk">
                                <img src="img/icons/poisk.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item2">
                                <img src="img/icons/Инстаграм_копия.png" alt="">
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__item2"><span class="menu__item2_tel">+7 499 110 58 32</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-menu2">
                    <ul class="menu-list3">
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/RF.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> EAS системы
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/Датчики.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> Датчики
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/Этикетки.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> Этикетки
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/аксессуары.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> аксессуары
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/Исходная_маркировка_st.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> Исходная Маркировка ST
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/RFID.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> RFID
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item3">
                            <img src="img/Слой_3_копия.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'> ALS Этикетки
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

[Тест на codeopen](https://codepen.io/datatest/pen/qvGjNJ)